# Create user with Passport & mysql

Tags: mysql, passport.js

I'm developing a MySql, Express, Angular, NodeJS application and I'm trying to wrap my head around signing up users, I can't find a propper source that provides to information I'm looking for.

I know how to create a user record with a username and password but only how to store the database as text and not hashed/salted.

I'm thinking I just need to find out how to created a hashed password when a user signs up. Then figure out how to place that hashed password in the database and then finally when a user wants to sign in compare the passwords. But it all feels a bit abstract and I can't find any information of passport does any of this.

Comment: Plz check this https://gist.github.com/manjeshpv/84446e6aa5b3689e8b84

Answer (score 0):

we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
 by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
},
function(req, email, password, done) {

    // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
    // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
    connection.query("select * from users where email = '"+email+"'",function(err,rows){
        console.log(rows);
        console.log("above row object");
        if (err)
            return done(err);
         if (rows.length) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
        } else {

            // if there is no user with that email
            // create the user
            var newUserMysql = new Object();

            newUserMysql.email    = email;
            newUserMysql.password = password; // use the generateHash function in our user model

            var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users ( email, password ) values ('" + email +"','"+ password +"')";
                console.log(insertQuery);
            connection.query(insertQuery,function(err,rows){
            newUserMysql.id = rows.insertId;

            return done(null, newUserMysql);
            }); 
        }   
    });
}));
```

For more details plz check this https://gist.github.com/manjeshpv/84446e6aa5b3689e8b84

Comment: I've figured out what my problem is. I'm having trouble seeing the how passport can retrieve a hashed password. I've seen some examples on how to grab a password during registration, hashing it and storing it so when the db is hacked the actual password isn't in there. But when a user logs in how does passport know if the password is correct, since it's hashed.